# Ignoring a line with Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

Sonar complains about a line.

```
Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME); // NOSONAR
```

Its problem is that

> "Thread.sleep" should not be used in tests
>
> Using Thread.sleep in a test is just generally a bad idea. It creates brittle tests that can fail unpredictably depending on environment ("Passes on my machine!") or load.

And it makes sense, this should be fixed. But my problem is: why doesn't the `NOSONAR` part has any effect here? It seems to work in other parts of the code where it's used, e.g. with

```
public static final String PASSWORD_FILE_NAME = "secret.txt"; // NOSONAR
```

it doesn't complain any more that there is a hardcoded password in the code. So why doesn't it work with the `Thread.sleep()` case?

I can see the issue both in SonarQube and in the SonarLint plugin for IntelliJ.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are basically hitting this problem : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1113

Which was that the `// NOSONAR` was not taken into account in tests.

This has been fixed in the latest release of the sonar java plugin release (3.11)

(On a side note, using NOSONAR is not great IMO, you should keep track of issue you don't want to fix using SonarQube rather than cluttering your code with comments that are linked to a specific external tool)

Comment: Thanks. A side-note about the side-note: it's true for SonarQube, but not an option currently for the SonarLint plugin.

Comment: Disagree with the note 'on a side'. When you have a good reason to disable a line I personally wouldn't want to be bothered anymore with 'problems'. Adding the comment // NOSONAR still enables you to keep track of these exceptions with a simple search. And you could add an extra comment explaining the reason of the exception.

Comment: How do you ignore a line in an XML file?